# Grails and dynamic modifications at runtime

Tags: security, grails, groovy, jvm

A deployable Grails war-File contains groovy files as well as a groovy.jar.

- Is there a groovy agent running when the application is deployed?
- Is it possible to make dynamic modifications for the application via Groovy at runtime?
- if yes, how can this be prevented?

Edit:
After the grails application war is deployed on let's say on Tomcat: Is there some kind of Groovy Shell/Process/Agent running where someone who has access to the system can connect to? And if this is possible can he make dynamic modifications to the application without touching any files on the file system?

Comment: What agent, this? http://groovy.dzone.com/articles/groovy-concurrency-action

Comment: Plus, what kind of modifications? Reloading controllers/services is enabled only for `development` environment. Class modifications via `metaClass` can't be disabled (well, you can compile with `Groovy++` and strictly type every class - then there won't be any dinamic invocations). But one can reload a class (and load a modified version) in runtime even in Java, so you there's no single way to "prevent" every kind of runtime modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Console plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/console) which provides a web-based version of the Groovy Console/Grails Console. Like the Swing-based app it has a `ctx` variable in scope to give you access to all of the app's Spring beans, and it will run arbitrary Groovy code in the context of your running web app, can access GORM, etc.

Obviously this is dangerous, so be sure to guard it with a [security plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)

I wrote a blog post a while back about using a similar web-based console (which I've since merged into the plugin) to fix a bug in a running server: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=155

Comment: Does this also mean there is no way to execute arbitrary Groovy code without this plugin?

Comment: No, there's no listener/console/etc. If there were it'd be a significant security risk. That's why the console and http://grails.org/plugin/remote-control plugins were created.

Comment: yet another probably stupid question: How are the groovy files bundled with the grails application executed if there is no groovy console?

Answer (score 1):

By default Grails apps do not ship with a console that will let you execute arbitrary Groovy code at runtime.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?